# How to load a local JSON object via D3 library in a Rails3 app?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, d3.js

In a file called `choropleth.js` with the following code:

```
d3.json("assets/data/us-counties.json", function(json) {
counties.selectAll("path")
  .data(json.features)
  .enter().append("svg:path")
  .attr("class", data ? quantize : null)
  .attr("d", path);
});
```

The JSON object I'm trying to load does not load. I get the following error:

> choropleth.js:18 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'features' of null

I've tried all variants of the path (absolute, relative to the .js file, relative to the view, etc) and none of it works. I'm using the d3 library, but I don't think that plays any part in this -- I think the question is simple "what URL to a specify to load a local `.json` file?"

Comment: That looks like it is trying to load a status JSON file from the app's assets. Any errors in the server's log? Where is the JSON file in the server's directory tree? Are you sure you have the right route?

Comment: The JSON is data about county boundary coordinates.  I put it in the assets/data directory (after making the data directory).  The file is at app/assets/data/us-counties.json. I don't have any routes set up for it.

Comment: You're calling "d3.json" and do not passing "json" parameter. That's why it is null.

Comment: Sorry Megas -- could you explain in a little more detail?  I'm really new to JavaScript and web programming in general.  I was trying to learn from this example: http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/choropleth.html

Comment: From your link I understood that it's ajax, geo thing calls to somewhere, it didn't receive any data and then calls the callback with null parameter.

Comment: My understanding was/is that it is not receiving any data because the path 'assets/data/us-counties.json' is not actually giving it my locale json file.  I think mu was on to something when he mentioned the routes.

Are there any JavaScript debugging tools that would help me localize the problem?  I still think it is a matter of using a different URL to request the .json or specifying a route, but I would like to pinpoint it.

Comment: You could put a static JSON file in `app/public/data/us-counties.json` and access it as `/data/us-counties.json`. I'm not sure where the `/assets` router would want a JSON file.

Comment: Thanks mu.  That makes sense.  I tried, though, and I get `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/data/us-counties.json")` -- but at least this gives me a better avenue to explore.  I'll try setting up a controller to serve the JSON.

Answer (score 1):

see my answer to question [1418350](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12921206/how-to-load-a-local-json-object-to-d3-js-frontend-with-django/14183501#14183501) : basically you need to provide two arguments for the json callback, the first being *error*, e.g.:

```
d3.json("world-countries.json", function(error, json) {
   // your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your callback function is passed null, that's because it failed to load the file. There could be a number of different causes for this. An excellent way to figure out why the file isn't loading is to use WebKit's developer tools and the network inspector.

For example, if you don't have the correct URL, you'll see a 404 error and the requested resource will appear red. If the server fails to generate the file with an error, you might see a 500 error instead.

Likewise, if you're viewing a local file (with a file:// URL in the address bar) and trying to load another local file via d3.json, you'll see a security exception because browsers don't allow you to access local files with XMLHttpRequest. [D3's README](https://github.com/mbostock/d3) has instructions on starting a web server to circumvent this error.