# How to load a local JSON object to D3.js frontend with Django?

Tags: xml, django, d3.js

I'm trying to create a d3.js visualization with a django backend.
I'm trying to render some json into a map:

```
     d3.json("world-countries.json", function(json) {
        self.countries.selectAll("path")
        .data(json.features)
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("d", self.path)
        .on("mouseover", function(d) {
            d3.select(this).style("fill","#6C0");})
        .on("mouseout", function(d) {
            d3.select(this).style("fill","#000000");})
    });
```

but I keep getting the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'features' of null
```

I'm not sure how to access json objects through Django; does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I'm guessing you have a path error in "world-countries.json" because that error is telling you that the json you are passing in is null.

Comment: How is "world-countries.json" a local json object? Sounds like a URL to me.

Answer (score 1):

check what version of D3 you are using.
I had the same problem and it turns out the callback needs *two* arguments - error and data.

Example:

```
d3.json("world-countries.json", function(error, json) {
   // your code
}
```

since the first argument is 'error' - when there is no error it appears that the json object is null.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to serve the page from a web server to avoid path and cross Domain issues. This can be easy and fast acomplished with node.js and the connect npm or with python as the author of d3js used to do it.

I you want to process json files in general you should Need to provide some upload mechanism. If you you happen to use Chrome there could be a Switch as reported in this stackoverflow question:

[Load local JSON files via file:// triggers cross-domain null origin violation, solution? (jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3851691/load-local-json-files-via-file-triggers-cross-domain-null-origin-violation-s)

so this is more of a Ajax-json-crossdomain issue not d3js

HTH